# A Palestinian trying to escape and get refugee status

Tags: refugees

I live in Palestine and have a Palestinian passport. 
Recently due to sharia law my life has become in danger and I must move to any country and ask for a refugee status. I contacted related authorities but my country was of little help, even against me so I am stuck taking action on my own.
I tried applying for a visitors visa in Norway but got refused after 8 weeks of waiting.
Is there a reasonable plan I can take to move away and ask for a refugee status?

Comment: Depending on the reasons, you may want to consider requesting assistance from the Israeli side. While they generally don't intervene in the Palestinian matters, they will not deport you back if you make it to Israel and prove that your life is genuinely in danger.

Comment: Israel has refused to even listen to me nor let me in. I had to have the un force me in just so I can stay for a couple of days

Comment: no country will let you in if you tell them you want to stay there. You need to ask for the refugee status when you are *already* there. If you're already in Israel - talk to the tons of human rights groups there about how to do that

Comment: It's not actually true that "no country will let you in if you tell them you want to stay there".

Comment: @DJClayworth well, for most parts, at least. I'm not familiar with a way to go to the embassy and get a refugee visa. Most countries would not allow embassies posted in their capitals do that.

Comment: You may get a refugee visa if you're applying for a refugee status in a third country, in some cases. If that's what you meant, @DJClayworth

Comment: You can show up at the borders of various countries and apply for asylum there.

Comment: You'll need to actually cross the border to be able to apply though...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The immediate choice would be Jordan. If your life is in danger *from the state itself* then Jordan can not refuse refugee status to you, that's the [convention](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convention_relating_to_the_Status_of_Refugees). You need to convince them of this, however. Details on getting to Jordan can be found in [this article](https://kamelhawwash.com/2015/08/24/for-palestinians-crossing-the-allenby-bridge-tofrom-jordan-is-ultimate-humiliation/) . Be safe and best of luck!

However, if you are only in danger from your family then you need to find ways to safety in your home country.

Edit: if you have a genuine convention refugee claim then the generic problem is that airlines won't allow you to board if they believe the destination country won't admit you because they would need to transport you back and would be fined. So you need a country where this is not a problem. As you can -- possibly -- reach Jordan on land, this is not a problem and also Jordan allows you without visa. Wikipedia has a great list about  [the Visa requirements for Palestinian citizens](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visa_requirements_for_Palestinian_citizens). If you can get to Tel Aviv and have the money to fly, then perhaps try for an eVisa from Georgia, there are several direct flights. You just need to get to another country.

Comment: I read the article you linked to... I crossed the British border many times, and not even once they talked to me in my native language or let me in without questioning, yet he is complaining that the Israelis are actually checking who he is and are trying to speak to him in his native language. And they say the Israelis are racists, go figure...

Comment: Well it's family and I have family in Jordan too. Lucky right now I am in Israel so I can true visa. Thanks